# How can I wait until an IndexedDB instance is closed?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

The IndexedDB method close [is synchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase), how can I wait until close has finished? My usecase is that I close IndexedDB after automated tests and then before the next test, delete the database and re-open it.

The problem I'm seeing is that sometimes [indexedDB.deleteDatabase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory#deleteDatabase) fires the blocked event because the database hasn't yet been closed asynchronously (as you can see from deleteDatabase's documentation that I linked to). What I'm not entirely sure about is if the database will still be deleted in this case, despite the blocked event being fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wait for close completed events, just close, delete the database and re-open it.

As you can see in IndexedDB API doc, close method does not dispatch completed event, but database delete method does. Anyways you don't need to listen these events.

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is that sometimes [indexedDB.deleteDatabase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory#deleteDatabase) fires the blocked event, likely because the database hasn't been closed yet. It's still unclear to me though if the database will still be deleted, eventually, in this case.

Comment: It is because you open db without closing all connection.

Comment: Not that I can tell, no. First of all, this happens before I try to open the DB and I have called close on the database at this point. Second, I'm quite sure this is because close hasn't yet finished before I call deleteDatabase (the documentation does say that deleteDatabase fires blocked if the database isn't yet closed).

Comment: Deleting before closing is ok. Close don't get block delete. Make sure your test not run in parallel.

Comment: I am seeing similar issues with opening and closing connects. It's not an option for me to delete the database to be able to get a callback on complete, so I'm in a pickle.

Comment: I have the issue that deleting DB was blocked. There were no operation on the DB. So closing DB before deleting it works! Tested in mobile version of Safari, FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The database cannot be closed if there are transactions still running, so that could be why. Do you have something like this?

```
IndexedDB.open("mydb").onsuccess = function(e) {
  db = e.target.result;
  trans = db.transaction("someobjectstore");
  os = trans.getObjectStore("someobjectstore");
  os.put("blah");
  db.close();
}
```

If so, it could be that the transaction is still running.

Regardless, the database will still be deleted if you get the blocked event... when all connections to it are closed.

When you instantiate a connection to the database ensure that you have assigned an onversionchange handler to the resulting db. That could help debug what's going on.

```
IndexedDB.open("mydb").onsuccess = function(e) {
  db = e.target.result;
  db.onversionchange = function(e) {
    console.log("got versionchange event: " + e);
  }
  trans = db.transaction("someobjectstore");
  os = trans.getObjectStore("someobjectstore");
  os.put("blah");
  db.close();
}
```

Comment: It happens only spuriously, I think it's just because the asynchronous close operation hasn't finished yet. If you're correct in that the delete succeeds anyhow I won't need to know when close has finished (and can ignore the blocked event).